# linq to entites query to object Data Source

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm new to C# and visual studio - using community edition 2013.  I'm having a disconnect here understanding how to use Linq to Entites to fill my Data Source.  I've created an Entity Model and built the project and then added an object data source that represents a couple of tables in the database.  I've dragged one of the tables to my form to create a simple data bound form and when I run the application there is no data display presumably because the Data Source is empty.  I'm wondering how I fill that data source using Linq?

I would assume I do something like:

```
CustomerEntities db = new CustomerEntities();
var customers = from c in db.Customers
select c;
```

Only thing is that will return the query into the local customers variable. How do I go about filling the data source instead?

BTW this is in the form1_load event procedure.

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess everyone else knows how to do this.  Through lots of struggling I came up with this.  Others can correct me if I'm incorrect but I was basically trying to fill the wrong thing.  The proper thing to fill is the bindingSource on the form:

```
CustomerEntities db = new CustomerEntities();
var Customers = from c in db.Customers
select c;

foreach (Customer item in Customers)
customerBindingSource.Add(item);
```

Thats It!  I hope that this helps someone just starting out. If there is any constructive criticism, I'm open to it.

Thanks,
Rich